# How to avoid that AWS Amplify OAuth tries to parse every oauth process

Tags: react-native, aws-amplify

I'm working with a react-native application where i have implement the Authentication flow using AWS Amplify and Federated signin. This is the amplify configuration:

```
Auth: {
      identityPoolId: 'XXX',
      region: 'XXX',
      mandatorySignIn: false,
      userPoolId: 'XXX',
      userPoolWebClientId: 'XXX',
      oauth: {
        domain: env.AWS_OAUTH_DOMAIN,
        scope: ['email', 'profile', 'openid','aws.cognito.signin.user.admin', 'given_name', 'family_name', 'user_gender', 'user_birthday', 'user_location'],
        redirectSignIn: myapp://signin,
        redirectSignOut: myapp://logout,
        responseType: 'code',
      },
    },
```

Everything works fine. Until now.

Now i have to add another OAuth authentication for other purposes (connecting Strava to my application). Everything works fine, until the Strava authorization dialog redirect to my app at the url: `runcard://profilo/servizi?code=XXX&scope=activity%3Aread%2Cread` (this callback url is different from the one i've set for amplify configuration). Once redirected, amplify is there, ready to raise an exception by Amplify OAuth:

```
WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_a.accessToken')
```

I believe that since the callback url has a `code` parameter, Amplify is trying to do the job himself. Without success.

Does anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Not a real solution, but i used a workaround, i'll post it here.

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of the issue!

Amplify is specifically looking for a param in any deeplinked URL called `code`.

I too was using `code` for a purpose other than the oauth callback (sign up confirmation code).

Changing the param to anything else (e.g. `confirmationCode`) prevents the `accessToken` error.

Comment: But you can't change the param name when using a third part service, like the case in the question (Strava).

Answer (score 1):

At the end, I've used this workaround: I removed the Amplify listener and I added a new listener that will parse only Amplify OAuth URLs.

```
Amplify.configure({ ... });
Analytics.getInstance();

// Workaround: this is to avoid that Amplify OAuth try to parse EVERY url as a OAuth callback url
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59883011/how-to-avoid-that-aws-amplify-oauth-tries-to-parse-every-oauth-process

Linking.removeAllListeners('url');
Linking.addEventListener('url', (url) => {
  if (url.url.indexOf(AWS_OAUTH_REDIRECT_SIGNIN !== -1 || url.url.indexOf(AWS_OAUTH_REDIRECT_SIGNOUT) !== -1) {
    Amplify.Auth._handleAuthResponse(url.url);
   }
});
```

AWS_OAUTH_REDIRECT_SIGNIN and AWS_OAUTH_REDIRECT_SIGNOUT are the same specified in Amplify configuration:

```
AWS: {
    Auth: {
      oauth: {
        redirectSignIn: AWS_OAUTH_REDIRECT_SIGNIN,
        redirectSignOut: AWS_OAUTH_REDIRECT_SIGNOUT,
        responseType: 'code'
      }
    }
}
```